# Can you find the missing lad and the treasure?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, treasure-hunt

<sub>This is an entry in the [27<sup>th</sup> Fortnightly Topic Challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/fortnightly-topic-challenge-27-treasure-hunt).</sub>

---

$\mathtt{Once \ upon \ a \ time, \ there \ was \ a \ young \ sailor. \ This \ young \ sailor, \ however, \ was \ a \  pirate. \ The \ scourge \ of \ the \ seas.\\ \ You \ may \ have \ heard \ of \ him \ - \ the \ infamous \ Blackbeard!\\ \ With \ his \ band \ of  \ cutthroat \ pirates, \ he \ stalked \ the \ seven \ seas, \ in \ his \ ship\ - \ The \ Queen \ Anne's \ Revenge!}$

$\mathtt{ Blackbeard \ terrorized \ the \ ocean, \ until \ the \ day \ that \ he \ vanished.\\ \ For \ centuries, \ nothing \ was \ known \ of \ what \ became \ of \ him \ - \ until \ yesterday.\\ \ Yesterday, \ we \ discovered \ a \ shipwreck.\\ \ Excitedly, \ our \ volunteers \ dug \ it \ up, \ until \ we \ found \ the \ name \ - \ The \  Queen \  Anne's \  Revenge. }$

$\mathtt { After \ a \ moment \ of \ stunned \ silence, \ everyone \ started \ talking \ madly.\\ \ In \ all \ of \ the \ confusion, \ nobody \ noticed \ when \ a \ young \ lad \ disappeared. }$

$\mathtt{ It \ was \ only \ when \ people \ started \ leaving \ that \ the \ lad's \ disappearance\\ was \ noticed.\\ \ Then \ everybody \ started \ scouring \ the \ beachside, \ but \ the \ search \ turned \ up \ empty.\\ \ The \ only \ thing \ that \ they \ found \ was \ this \ scrap \ of \ paper.\\ \ Perhaps \ you \ can \ find \ him? }$

$$\bbox[#f9f7db, 10px]
{
\mathcal{Ahoy! \ \color{#8a23a9}Maybe \ you \ think \ that \ yer \ goin' \ to \ find \ me \ treasure.\\ \ Well, \ you \ better \ think \ \color{#4e5d6b}t\color{#4e5d6b}wice.\\ \ In \ \color{#4e5d6b}order \ for \ you \ to \ find \ it, \ you've \ got \ to \ \color{#4e5d6b}go \ on \ a \ \color{#4e5d6b}quest.\\ \ So \ you've \ got \ \color{#4e5d6b}2 \ options: \ Sail \ the \ \color{#4e5d6b}7 \ seas, \ or \ give \ up.\\ \ Whaddya \ say? \ If \ ye \ insist \ in \ the \ t\color{#4e5d6b}reasure, \ carry \ on.\\ \ The \ first \ place \ where \ you'\color{#4e5d6b}ve \ got \ te \ go \ is \ hidden \ in \ this \ note, \ \color{#4e5d6b}along \ with \ a \ complimentary \ second.\\ \ Good \ luck... \ Or \ not.}
}
$$

$$
{
\huge\mathbf {Instructions}
}
$$

$\mathbb{Each \ station \ should \ reveal \ a \ tinyurl \ to \ a \ Google \ Maps \ location.\\ \ You \ will \ use \ information \ from \ different \ stations \ all \ over \ -\\ \ there's \ no \ telling \ what \ might \ be \ useful.}$

---

$$
{
\huge\mathbf {Station \ 1}
}
$$

$$
{
\mathsf{Your \ destination \ is \ hidden \ in \ the \ note.}
}
$$

---

$$
{
\huge\mathbf {Station \ 2}
}
$$

$$
{
\mathsf{Your \ destination \ is \ hidden \ in \ the \ note.}
}
$$

---

$$
{
\huge\mathbf {Station \ 3}
}
$$

$$
{
\mathsf {This \ is \ a \ crossword. \ The \ clues \ are \ below. \ To \ decipher \ them, \ use \ a \ Vigenere \ cipher \ with \ the \ key \ as \ your \ previous \ destination.\\ \ '////' \ indicates \ a \ blank \ space.}
}
$$

```
  ┏━━━━┳━━━━┳━━━━┳━━━━┳━━━━┳━━━━┳━━━━┓
  ┃ 1d ┃////┃ 2d ┃////┃ 1a ┃    ┃    ┃
  ┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫  
  ┃ 2a ┃ 3d ┃    ┃    ┃////┃////┃////┃
  ┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫
  ┃ 3a ┃    ┃    ┃////┃4d4a┃ 5d ┃////┃
  ┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫
  ┃    ┃////┃////┃ 5a ┃    ┃    ┃ 6d ┃
  ┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫
  ┃    ┃////┃////┃////┃    ┃////┃    ┃
  ┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫
  ┃////┃ 6a ┃    ┃ 7d ┃////┃7a8d┃    ┃
  ┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫
  ┃ 8a ┃    ┃////┃ 9a ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃
  ┗━━━━┻━━━━┻━━━━┻━━━━┻━━━━┻━━━━┻━━━━┛
```

<sub>[(image version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMbtP.png)</sub>

$$
{
\mathsf {Across}
}
$$

$\mathtt{ 1. \ Qdu \ evda\ dw \ gzxs \ lrsglg \ vx \ noc \ ssxl.\\ 2. \ S \ rocalgy \ qa \ lwe \ Uvvslm \ Rsht.\\ \ Knf \ qe \ unvt \ fzbe \ p \ smaltnkr \ vtctnjxno \ gzpt \ qa \ lwe \ xnki \ ywh \ edvmq \ ijikxdn.\\3. \ S \ Hhixwhpmnjtiia \ fd.\\ 4. \ Dtadr.\\ 5. \ Lwe \ lvkiavpw \ qebjwtn \ O \ nfs \ A. Lbmqlm \ gzt \ dqsxtrmaut \ bmgotev \ R scd N.\\ 6. \ Owab \ lgj \ gmg \ ac \ tpr \ kjn.\\7. \ Fdvi \ fudtqn.\\8. \ S \ siotacg \ qakirczwct, \ evlwocg \ wmcmrvxno \ rpeekgsiiwak, \ pnl \ n \ ugemcq \ aactz \ urwz \ s \ uab \ bds \ gcl.\\ 9. \ Owab \ lgj \ dw \ gg \ p \ pqnfd.}$

$$
{
\mathsf {Down}
}
$$

$\mathtt{ 1. \ Lwe \ xymgat \ bx \ lhmew \ noc \ zsze \ ubftyubftyubfty.\\ 2. \ Dnivt \ ac \ tpr \ hpsb... \\3. \ Lwe \ lraiy \ eug \ haqyk \ pczbkh \ tpr \ kzy \ qa \ s \ qoig, \ ac \ tpr \ htrxrljat \ osittr \ svaqaki \ cpngh.\\4. \ Ytligacocf \ yaox. \ Bz, \ dh. \ Wu!\\5. \ Fdtwsx.\\6. \ Owab \ gzxs \ xhrolm \ vk \ cob.\\7. \ Kdmmgzxno \ gzpt \ qf \ fdt \ i \ cjdbtre \ dn \ buw \ lej.\\8. \ Fdt \ ichaikntae \ bb \ lwia \ cmoztr.}$

---

$$
{
\huge\mathbf {Station \ 4}
}
$$

$$
{
\mathsf {This \ is \ a \ wordoku/sudoku. \ Once \ you \ have \ solved \ it, \ there \ is \ a \  link \ hidden.\\ (Dots \ are \ not \ part \ of \ it.)}
}
$$

```
  ┏━━━━┳━━━━┳━━━━┳━━━━┳━━━━┳━━━━┳━━━━┳━━━━┳━━━━┓
  ┃ j. ┃ 5  ┃ 8  ┃    ┃ u  ┃  . ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃
  ┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫  
  ┃ s  ┃ .  ┃    ┃    ┃ g  ┃ 1  ┃ 8  ┃    ┃    ┃
  ┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫
  ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃ j  ┃ 5  ┃ s  ┃ p  ┃
  ┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫
  ┃ 8  ┃    ┃ p  ┃    ┃ 5  ┃ u  ┃    ┃ 1  ┃ g  ┃
  ┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫
  ┃    ┃ 1  ┃ u  ┃ p  ┃ s  ┃   .┃ 4  ┃    ┃    ┃
  ┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫
  ┃    ┃ s  ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃ p  ┃ 8  ┃    ┃
  ┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫
  ┃ 4  ┃    ┃    ┃ u  ┃    ┃ s. ┃    ┃ p  ┃ 8  ┃
  ┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫
  ┃ p  ┃.   ┃ 1  ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃    ┃
  ┣━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━╋━━━━┫
  ┃.   ┃ 8  ┃ s  ┃    ┃ p  ┃ 4  ┃ j  ┃ 5  ┃    ┃
  ┗━━━━┻━━━━┻━━━━┻━━━━┻━━━━┻━━━━┻━━━━┻━━━━┻━━━━┛
```

<sub>[(image version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZEjs.png)</sub>

---

$$
{
\huge\mathbf {Station \ 5}
}
$$

[steganography](/questions/tagged/steganography)

$$
{
\mathsf {Remember, \ numbers \ are \ not \ Vigenered.}
}
$$

$\tiny\tiny{story}$
$\mathtt{2-3-4\\ 1-5-3\\ 3-1-1\\ 7\\ 5-5-1\\ 6\\ 4-5-2}$

---

$$
{
\huge\mathbf {Station \ 6}
}
$$

$\mathsf{There \ are \ two \ kinds \ of \ dragons: \ Rationals \ and \ predators.\\ Gray \ rationals \ and \ red \ predators \ always \ tell \ the \ truth; \ red \ rationals \ and \ gray \ predators \ always \ lie.}$

$\mathtt{Dragon \ A:Stg4ud2 \ \\ Dragon \ B: \ Sw5yz6g\\ Dragon \ C: \ Lrhyf4w }$

$\tiny{The \ following \ puzzle \ was \ taken \ from \ a \ book \ entitled \ Classic \ Logic \ Puzzles, \ by \ J. \ J. \ Mendora \ Fernandez, \ George \ J. \ Summers, \ and \ Norman \ D. \ Willis.}$

$\mathtt{A.\\ \ 1. \ Ask \ B \ what \ my \ type \ is; \ he \ will \ give \ you \ a \ truthful \ answer.\\2. \ C \ is \ red.\\B.\\1. \ A \ and \ I \ are \ both \ rationals.\\2. \ C \ is \ a \ predator.\\C.\\1. \ A \ and \ B are \ both \ predators.\\2. \ B \ is \ gray.}$

---

$$
{
\huge\mathbf {Station \ 7}
}
$$

$\mathsf{Sheet \ music. \ The \ chords \ are \ Vigenered. \ How \ could \ this \ reveal \ a \ tinyurl? \ You'll \ see...}$

[image: unfortunately, this part depends on images. This is a piece of sheet music.]

---

$$
{
\huge\mathbf {Station \ 8}
}
$$

$\mathsf{This \ may \ look \ like \ weird. \ That's \ because \ it's \ your \ treasure! \ To \ fully \ win \ your \ treasure, \ you \ must \ solve \ this \ unaided. \ Standard \ Vigenere.}$

$\mathtt{Jabberwok, \ thy \ time \ hath \ come! \ Come, \ valiantly \ face \ thy \ destiny!\\ \ But \ as \ thou \ art \ cowardly, \ thou \ cannot.\\ Let \ us \ then \ never \ see \ thy \ horrid \ scaly \ face \ for \ evermore! \ Under \ sea, \ on \ Earth, \ in \ the \ sky \ above! \ Go \ forth, \ vile \ creature!}$

$\mathtt{Drearily, \ walk \ home \ disgraced. \ The \ Jabberwok \ hath \ returned, \ O \ people!\ Returned \ to \ its \ midnight \ hauntings, \ to \ terrorize \ the \ villages!\ 6 \ weeks, \ and \ it \ will \ be \ upon \ us! \ Flee! \ Warriors, \ to \ arms! \ TO \ ARMS!}$$

---

[Here](http://www.cs.du.edu/~snarayan/crypt/vigenere.html) is the Vigenere thing I used.

Comment: Ugh, MathJax Overkill.

Comment: @MOehm part of the puzzle needed it, and I didn't want to make that too obvious, so... *\*shrug**

Comment: How did you change the font like that? and How did you color the capital M purple? I want to do it too in my coming puzzling novel.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat - to see the source of any puzzle, you can click the [edit] link. Also, could you please not comment so often on random puzzles of mine? It's starting to get a drop irritating.

Answer (score 4):

The instructions tell us that each station should produce a tinyurl that leads to a Google Maps link. These URLs have codes that are made up of case-insenitive letters and digits. (I first thought that these codes were always seven characters long, but that's not true. Tinyurl even allows you to have custom codes.)

The results are the names of places – countries, states, cities or islands. They are used as Vigenère key in order to reveal the puzzles in some stations. It is not clear where they should be used. Here's a brief sketch of the input and output so far:

> Station 1: *note* → **HAWAII**
>  Station 2: *note* → **SPAIN**
>  Station 3: **SPAIN** → *crossword* → **CHINA**
>  Station 4: *wordoku* → **FRANCE**
>  Station 5: **FRANCE** → *numbers* → **MAINE**
>  Station 6: **MAINE** → *dragons* → (**KOREA**), (**ROCHESTER**), **EASTER ISLAND**
>  Station 7: **EASTER ISLAND** → *music* → **ALASKA**
>  Station 8: ? → *final* → ?
>
>  Still unused keys: **HAWAII**, **CHINA**, (**KOREA**), (**ROCHESTER**), **ALASKA**

At the moment, the treasure hunters are trying to solve Station 8, where the treasure is buried!

#### Station 1

The key should be hidden in the note.

> The note has several letters highlighted in another colour:
>
>    Ahoy! **M**aybe you think that yer goin' to find me treasure.
>    Well, you better think **tw**ice.
>    In **o**rder for you to find it, you've got to **g**o on a **q**uest.
>    So you've got **2** options: Sail the **7** seas, or give up.
>    Whaddya say? If ye insist in the t**r**easure, carry on.
>    The first place where you'**v**e got te go is hidden in this note,
>        **a**long with a complimentary second.
>    Good luck... Or not.
>
>  Most of the special letters are highlighted in a dull slate grey, which is hard to make out. The capital M, however, is rendered in purple. The hex code of the colour's RGB values can be seen in edit mode; it's [**8a23a9**](https://www.google.co.il/maps/place/Hawaii,+USA/@20.4022368,-162.000983,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x7bffdb064f79e005:0x4b7782d274cc8628!8m2!3d19.8967662!4d-155.5827818?hl=en) and it leads to **HAWAII**.

#### Station 2

This key was found by Techidiot:

> The highlighted letters are **M two gq27rva**. The **M** has been used in Station 1 and the **two** serves only to mark the next letters as belonging to Station 2, as the OP has said in a comment.
>
>  With the last seven, [**gq27rva**](https://www.google.co.il/maps/place/Spain/@40.2085,-3.713,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0xc42e3783261bc8b:0xa6ec2c940768a3ec!8m2!3d40.463667!4d-3.74922?hl=en), as tinyurl code we get a link to **SPAIN**.

#### Station 3

The Vigenère key for the crossword clues ...

> ... is **SPAIN** from Station 2.

The decoded crossword clues are:

> **Across**
>
>  1. You will do this dearly if you fail. (3)
>  2. A country in the Middle East. Can be made from a sentence
>     declaring that in the past you moved quickly. (4)
>  3. A Shakespeareian no. (3)
>  4. Leave. (2)
>  5. The distance between G and A. Double the difference
>     between E and F. (4)
>  6. What you get in the sun. (3)
>  7. Nova scotia. (2)
>  8. A digging instrument, without exceeding expectations,
>     and a creepy laugh from a fat old guy. (2)
>  9. What you do to a piano.
>
>  **Down**
>
>  1. The plural of where you make moneymoneymoney. (5)
>  2. Lying in the past... (3)
>  3. The deity who sails across the sky in a boat, in the perpetual
>     battle against chaos. (2)
>  4. Gelatinous glop. Oh, oh. Oh! (3)
>  5. Not off. (2)
>  6. What this puzzle is not. (4)
>  7. Something that is not a problem on the web. (2)
>  8. Not applicable to this puzzle. (2)

The solutions to the clues are:

> **Across**
>
>  1. PAY (found by Rubio)
>  2. IRAN – I ran
>  3. NAY
>  4. GO
>  5. TONE (from note G and A is one tone and from E to F is a half-tone.)
>  6. TAN
>  7. NS (abbr)
>  8. HO (sHOvel? Ho, ho, ho!)
>  9. PLAY
>
>  **Down**
>
>  1. MINTS
>  2. LAY (past tense of to lie)
>  3. RA
>  4. GOO
>  5. ON
>  6. EASY
>  7. NP (abbr)
>  8. NA (abbr)

The solved crossword is:

> ```
>       ┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
>       │ M │ ■ │ L │ ■ │ P │ A │ Y │
>       ├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
>       │ I │ R │ A │ N │ ■ │ ■ │ ■ │
>       ├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
>       │ N │ A │ Y │ ■ │ G │ O │ ■ │
>       ├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
>       │ T │ ■ │ ■ │ T │ O │ N │ E │
>       ├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
>       │ S │ ■ │ ■ │ ■ │ O │ ■ │ A │
>       ├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
>       │ ■ │ T │ A │ N │ ■ │ N │ S │
>       ├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
>       │ H │ O │ ■ │ P │ L │ A │ Y │
>       └───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
> ```

The URL for the next station is ...

> ... found in the diagonal: [**mrytony**](https://www.google.co.il/maps/place/China/@30.1089745,67.4809542,3z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x31508e64e5c642c1:0x951daa7c349f366f!8m2!3d35.86166!4d104.195397?hl=en). It leads us **CHINA**.

A note on the Vigenère key: I had guessed the key before Techidiot has posted his answer. This was possibe, because the plain text is English. I think that working backwards may also be applicable to other stations.

#### Station 4

This station does not require a key and Techidiot has already solved the wordoku:

> ```
>       ┌───┬───┬───╥───┬───┬───╥───┬───┬───┐
>       │ j.│ 5 │ 8 ║ s │ u │ p.║ 1 │ g │ 4 │
>       ├───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───┤
>       │ s │ p.│ 4 ║ 5 │ g │ 1 ║ 8 │ u │ j │
>       ├───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───┤
>       │ 1 │ u │ g ║ 4 │ 8 │ j ║ 5 │ s │ p │
>       ╞═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╡
>       │ 8 │ 4 │ p ║ j │ 5 │ u ║ s │ 1 │ g │
>       ├───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───┤
>       │ g │ 1 │ u ║ p │ s │ 8.║ 4 │ j │ 5 │
>       ├───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───┤
>       │ 5 │ s │ j ║ 1 │ 4 │ g ║ p │ 8 │ u │
>       ╞═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╡
>       │ 4 │ j │ 5 ║ u │ 1 │ s.║ g │ p │ 8 │
>       ├───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───┤
>       │ p │ g.│ 1 ║ 8 │ j │ 5 ║ u │ 4 │ s │
>       ├───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───┤
>       │ u.│ 8 │ s ║ g │ p │ 4 ║ j │ 5 │ 1 │
>       └───┴───┴───╨───┴───┴───╨───┴───┴───┘
> ```

Taking the characters from the dotted cells, we get [**jpp8sgu**](https://www.google.co.il/maps/place/France/@46.2159532,2.2087677,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0xd54a02933785731:0x6bfd3f96c747d9f7!8m2!3d46.227638!4d2.213749?hl=en), which leads us to **FRANCE**.

#### Station 5

This puzzle consists of numbers only, so Vigenère can't be applied here directly.

> The puzzle has a steganography tag and the small note "story". Treat the three-number combos as sentence – word – letter references. Single numbers are just that: digits. The "story" hint tells us not to use the yellow note, but the story itself, which begins with "Oce upon a time", as source.
>
>  The result is **let7c6f**, to which we must apply the Vigenère key **FRANCE** from the previous station to get [**gnt7p6d**](https://www.google.co.il/maps/place/Maine,+USA/@45.196607,-71.2598983,7z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4cb01dde1d538ad5:0xd679cc6f6720a8d0!8m2!3d45.253783!4d-69.4454689?hl=en), which leads to **MAINE**.

#### Station 6

This liar puzzle is in plain text.

> Each dragon has a code, which we can decode with the Vigenère key **MAINE** to get:
>
>     Dragon A: Stg4ud2 → [**gty4hz2**](https://www.google.co.il/maps/place/Korea/@37.9224037,123.175344,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x356263108b3d1c3b:0x86416151fc4a3997!8m2!3d37.6639976!4d127.9784585?hl=en) → **KOREA**
>     Dragon B: Sw5yz6g → [**gw5qm6c**](https://www.google.co.il/maps/place/Rochester,+NY,+USA/@43.1854445,-77.6865426,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89d6b3059614b353:0x5a001ffc4125e61e!8m2!3d43.16103!4d-77.6109219?hl=en) → **ROCHESTER**
>     Dragon C: Lrhyf4w → [**zrzlb4k**](https://www.google.co.il/maps/place/Easter+Island/@-27.1259105,-109.4789002,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x9947f017a8d4ae2b:0xbbe5b3edc02a2db6!8m2!3d-27.11299!4d-109.3495806?hl=en) → **EASTER ISLAND**
>
>  This is a liar puzzle, a type of puzzle I'm not terribly fond of. If we assume that B lies, A's first staement means that A lies, too. Since all of A's and B's stalements are false, C must be a grey rational, who tells the truth. That means that both A and B are grey predators, who always lie. Other possibilities seem to lead to contradictions, but I haven't explored them all.
>
>  So A and B are lying grey predators and C is a truthful grey rational. If the task is to find a truthful dragon, the solution is C with the key **EASTER ISLAND**.

#### Station 7

We are told to decode the chords.

> With the Vigenère key **EASTER**, the chords decode to:
>
>    C G F C Dm F Am C G Am C Em F Dm C
>
>  (I don't know whether the other two results from the previous station are needed, but I had already found out that **EASTER** is the only reasonable key that decoded to valid chords.)
>
>  The chords are:
>
>    **Am**: A, C, E 
>    **C**: C, E, G 
>    **Dm**: D, F, A 
>    **Em**: E, G, B 
>    **F**: F, A, C 
>    **G**: G, B, D
>
>  I don't know how to read the notes. There is no clef and the fact that there aren't always the same number of notes between bars probably means that they just serve to create a kind of code in conjunction with the chords, but I don't see how.
>
>  I've tried to make Bacon codes (5-bit binary numbers) from the notes where notes that cross the stave or notes that under the assumption of a violin clef woul be part of the chord are either 0 or 1. I've also tried to turn the notes into Morde signals where up/down mean dot/dash (or vice versa) and two consecutive equal notes are ignored. That all lead to nothing.
>
>  The solution is much simpler: Concatenate all the chords of the bars that have five notes instead of four and get [**gcfamcdm**](https://www.google.co.il/maps/place/Alaska,+USA/@56.6752662,167.6653664,3z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x5400df9cc0aec01b:0xbcdb5e27a98adb35!8m2!3d64.2008413!4d-149.4936733?hl=en). The link is to **ALASKA**

#### Station 8

So this is where the treasure is.

> There's a text set in typewriter font. It has a lot of capital letters and also a suspicious digit at the beginning of a sentence. All capital letters and the digit read:
>
>    JCBLUEG DTJOR6F WTOARMS
>
>  (The divisions are mine; the seven letter words would make good tinyurl keys.)
>
>  There are some uncertainties: There are several unused keys. I think that the excess keys from Station 6, the liar puzzle, can be discarded; they were probably only meant as wrong options. But even so, we haven't used **HAWAII** from Station1, **CHINA** from Station 3 and, of course, **ALASKA**, which we've just found in Station 7. Do we have to combine the keys? I would guess that the last key is the correct one, but that assumption has failed me several times during this treasure hunt, so I'm wary.
>
>  I'm not sure whether we are looking for a tinyurl link to a Google Maps page here or whether we get a tinyurl link at all. The introduction says "This is your treasure", so the solution might be a description of the treasure. The digit 6 supports the assumption that the result is a tinyurl, however. Or maybe an imgur link?
>
>  Taking only the capital letters plus digits, or the first letters in every sentence or all capital letters that are not the beginning of a sentence didn't get me anywhere.
>
>  Maybe I should try some more things, but frankly, I'm running a bit out of steam here.

Comment: (note: the two was supposed to indicate that Spain was the second station.)

Comment: @M Oehm OP hinted that the hex value of M which is 4d. tinyurl dddd gives Chesterfield airport. Not sure if its just a coincidence or relevant.

Comment: @Techidiot: Where did he say that, in TSL? I don't think that's a relevant link: It's a link to MapQuest, not Google Maps. Up to now, all codes have been 7 characters long and have led to a GM page with the name of a country highlighted in the sidebar. Maybe it's not always the name of a country, but I think the place should be marked with a pin.

Comment: @MOehm Yup. In TSL. Check if you can make sense out of [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35789233#35789233) and [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35802890#35802890) I have tried several things without any luck

Comment: @Techidiot: Thanks for the links. I've got it now. I was under the false impression that the tinyurl codes had to be seven characters long, but that's not true. The hex code is that of the colour and can be seen in the MathJax; I guess this is the puzzle te MathJax was needed for. I had tried it, but padded it with the M to get seven chars, which turned up blank, of course.

Comment: @MOehm Yes. It was Hawaii. :) I spent too much time to figure it out by combining it with M/4d etc

Comment: You're almost there with the steganography, but it's not paragraph/word/letter. One of those is wrong.

Comment: I'm trying out several things right now. It's a bit of trial and error, because there are paragraphs, lines (with hard line breaks in MathJax) and sentences. (But the first "sentence" is just "Ahoy", so 1-5-3 doesn't really work. I assume that word and letter are correct.)

Comment: station 3, 1A is likely PAY

Comment: The music part doesn't actually require musical knowledge.

Comment: Try looking for the ones that are different.

Answer (score 2):

Will start with a partial

> M two gq27rva - > These are the colored characters in the note.
>
>  I haven't figured out the first part yet. But, taking the second part and using it as tinyurl gives
>  tinyurl.com/gq27rva takes us to **SPAIN**
>
>
>  Taking this as a key for the clues part we get -
>
>  **ACROSS**
>  1. You will do this dearly if you fail.
>  2. A country in the Middle East. Can be made from a sentence declaring that in the past you moved quickly.
>  3. A Shakespeareian no.
>  4. Leave.
>  5. The distance between G and A.Double the difference between EandF.
>  6. What you get in the sun.
>  7. Nova scotia.
>  8. A digging instrument, without exceeding expectations, and a creepy laugh from a fat old guy.
>  9. What you do to a piano.
>
>  
>  **DOWN**
>
>  1. The plural of where you make moneymoneymoney.
>  2. Lying in the past...
>  3. The deity who sails across the sky in a boat, in the perpetual battle against chaos
>  4. Gelatinous glop. Oh, oh. Oh!
>  5. Notoff
>  6. What this puzzle is not.
>  7. Something that is not a problem on the web.
>  8. Not applicable to this puzzle
>
>
>  ATM, @M Oehm is done with solving the clues [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/49670/30887)

**WORD SUDOKU SOLUTION**

> [image]

Comment: Good work on solving the wordoku. If you connect the dots, it will lead you to another country.

Comment: @MOehm Thanks. I am taking off for now. You can continue solving.